# Unable to clone local directory in to remote github repository using jgit

Tags: java, github-api, jgit

i need to create a github directory in my local machine and i'm trying to clone it with my remote github repository.I tried in a lot of ways to clone a repo with jGit using the below code:

```
        package github;

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository;
import org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class PushToRemoteRepository {

    private static final String REMOTE_URL = "https://github.com/syndy1989/Modify.git";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
        // prepare a new folder for the cloned repository
        File localPath = File.createTempFile("TestGitRepository", "");
        if(!localPath.delete()) {
            throw new IOException("Could not delete temporary file " + localPath);
        }
        UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider upc = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("syndy1989", "xxxxx");
        // then clone
        System.out.println("Cloning from " + REMOTE_URL + " to " + localPath);
        Git result = Git.cloneRepository()
                .setURI(REMOTE_URL)
                .setDirectory(localPath)
                .setCredentialsProvider(upc)
                .call(); {

                    System.out.println(result);
                // now open the created repository
                FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
                Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(localPath)
                        .readEnvironment() // scan environment GIT_* variables
                        .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
                        .build(); {
                    Git git = new Git(repository);{
                        git.push()
                                .call();
                    }

                    System.out.println("Pushed from repository: " + repository.getDirectory() + " to remote repository at " + REMOTE_URL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i get shown the below error:

```
 Cloning from https://github.com/syndy1989/Modify.git to C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\TestGitRepository9138453641649961455
org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git@255b53dc
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: origin: not found.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:171)
    at github.PushToRemoteRepository.main(PushToRemoteRepository.java:47)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: origin: not found.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportLocal$1.open(TransportLocal.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportBundleFile$1.open(TransportBundleFile.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.open(Transport.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.openAll(Transport.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

I saw some examples using JGit and some other references like http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/
https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepository.java

Jar's used:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>corg.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.201406041058-rc3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.validation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

raw.json file(located in "C:\Git\raw.json" folder inside docker container)All i'm trying to do is to clone Git directory in to remote github repository to push my raw.json file using java code in an automated way. Please help me with the working example to create a git directory on local machine, connecting to remote git hub repository & pushing the .json file in to remote repository using java. Thanks in advance

Comment: You see the `Connection refused: connect github.com` error message? Check if something is wrong with your internet connection (are you behind a proxy?).

Comment: Hi @FlorianAlbrecht i have updated my code and error message. i changed my proxy settings. Now i'm getting the error "org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: origin: not found." Any advise on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you do all the stuff with the FileRepositoryBuilder? Just do your push on the created `result` object...

Comment: Forget what I wrote. Did you really read your example http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/ carefully?? Really? Step by step? The whole page?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried everything it just won't work. Could you please share the java snippet for push and pull. That would be helpful.